# Is there a simpler way to deploy to WebSphere?

Tags: ant, jakarta-ee, websphere, jacl

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046/can-someone-give-me-a-working-example-of-a-buildxml-for-an-ear-that-deploys-in) about deploying to WebSphere using the WAS ant tasks.

Is there a simpler way to do this?  In the past I have deployed to Tomcat by dropping a war file into a directory.  I was hoping there would be a similar mechanism for WebSphere that doesn't involve calling the IBM libraries or rely on RAD to be installed on your workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the concept of [WebSphere Rapid Deployment](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.wrd.freeform.doc/topics/cwrdrapid.html). It's supposed to be the same experience as what you describe for Tomcat.

Answer (score 4):

Just a hint: if you activate "Log command assistance commands" in System Administration / Console preferences, you will get a logfile in the server log directory that contains the jython scripts for all actions you did on the console. So you can just deploy your stuff per console the first time, and then grab the commands for later and feed them into `wsadmin.bat -lang jython "thecommandscomehere"` for the next deployment.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it could be using [Jython or jacl scripts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html). See those samples at IBM site.

**[EDIT]** Especially the `wsadminlib.py.zip` download near the bottom of the page contains a huge set of examples and helper functions to get you started.

Comment: That seems to be the only other way to do it...I'm not really sure if it's actually "simpler" though!

Comment: I personally have found the JACL approach to be "not fun"

Comment: JACL is depricated anyway, just use Jython

Answer (score 1):

WAS does provide a client jar containing some custom ant tasks. However they seem to be extremely bugy and dont work with remote servers.

[IBM ANT TASK Javadoc](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/public_html/api/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/InstallApplication.html)

Netbeans also has support for was 6 and 6.1 but this again is still quite buggy, however it can be useful for generating some the bindings files etc.