# How to build EAR/WAR for Websphere Application Server by Eclipse?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

IBM Rational Application Developer is very slow and has many problems.

I tried to use ant scripts to build EAR/WAR files for Websphere Application Server
but it did not work.

Comment: how about posting the relevant section of your build file?

Comment: In my experience, RAD is slow.  All the time.  No matter what.  Also in my experience, using Ant to built the ear/war files didn't have any problems.  When you say, "but it did not work" what do you mean?

Comment: Please describe the errors you're seeing, whether with Eclipse or Ant.  It is difficult to help with so little information.

Comment: Ummm... how about the JAR utility?

Answer (score 3):

If Ant can't find the WAS tasks, then it is likely that the WAS API's are missing from the Ant classpath.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046/can-someone-give-me-a-working-example-of-a-buildxml-for-an-ear-that-deploys-in) for other sample scripts and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure the jar file containing the `com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WSDL2Java` is in your `lib.path` classpath.

```
<taskdef name="wsdl2java"
    classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WSDL2Java">
    <classpath refid="lib.path"/>
</taskdef>
```

If you're on UNIX, you can scan for this class using code similar to:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jar" | while read file
do
    jar tvf $file | grep WSDL2Java && echo $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If RAD is slow, 
- try to upgrade to the latest FixPack available.
- read the following article https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/113606723/radtipsv754.pdf?version=1

Or contact support and explain more specifically the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you build the EAR/WAR, then open your browser, login to the admin console, then deploy your application.

If my understanding is correct, just add an instance of the WAS server to your workspace, and then right click on the server, select Add/Remove Projects and add your project. This way, you don't have to build the EAR/WAR file at all... Building your project is enough. If the build is successful, then RAD automatically builds the EAR/WAR and publishes the file to the server.

Atleast that's the way we do it.

Comment: I don't want to build it with RAD or WAS Admin Console, just script that i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a brand new version of Eclipse (like Helios or Indigo) that has the Marketplace, then there is the possibility of deploying directly to Websphere.  Here's a link about it:
[Announcing the new WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse V8.0.4](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/wasdev/entry/announcing_the_new_websphere_application_server_developer_tools_for_eclipse_v8_0_42?lang=en)