# deploy war to websphere through commandline

Tags: shell, ant, websphere

I am newbie to `websphere`.

I need to automate deployment of my war file on to the websphere using `ant` or `shell script`.

That ant target/ shell command should deploy and install my war.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

IBM provide a set of ant tasks for deploying applications to websphere. Take a look at this answer:

[Example of a build.xml for an EAR that deploys in WebSphere 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046/example-of-a-build-xml-for-an-ear-that-deploys-in-websphere-6)